# What are the rules of inflection in making an idiom?

Tags: idioms, comparatives, irregular-plurals, inflectional-morphology

Although the following expressions may sound local or unnatural to some, these are examples of idiomatic expressions I hear in *New York City*.

Does putting *plural emphasis* of a noun or *comparative emphasis* of an adjective make a *standard* form of *inflection* in using an idiomatic expression?

*Plural emphasis*

1 She is **playing *a lot of hookies***. *(Midtown Manhattan in New York City, 2023)*

Its base form is **playing hooky**.
Should it be said as 1A?

1A She is **playing hooky** *a lot*.

*Comparative emphasis*

2 He is **the biggest f_cking sh_t** out of my whole life.
*(Hell’s Kitchen section of New York City, ca. 2008)*

Its base form is used in the following example in greeting (2A):

2A [*Answering to “How are you doing?”*]

I’m [like] **a big sh_t**.

Should it be said as 2B?

2B I’m *totally* [like] **a big sh_t**.

Comment: *the biggest fucking shit* isn't an idiom. [Shit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shit) means "a worthless, offensive, or detestable person" and is modified by "biggest" and "fucking" in regular dictionary meanings. Although it's common to [infix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_infixation) "fucking" in all kinds of constructions. (I assume you mean big shit not big shot?) It's not exactly clear what your final example is intended to mean.

Comment: "playing a lot of hookies" is more interesting; it might make a question on its own.

Comment: Idioms resist manipulation. But variations are not disallowed totally.  'Fixed expressions and idioms in English: A corpus-based approach' by Rosamund Moon looks at the normally accepted limitations on quite a few  individual idioms (there aren't fixed rules). 'She is playing a lot of hookies' is  (many truancies) fairly [could there be different types?] clear to one knowing the basic idiom, but uses a non-standard countification. I'd say it's fine in informal usage, quirky, but better avoided in formal contexts.

Comment: @Stuart F “the biggest fucking shit” is NOT an idiom but “(a) big shit” is an idiom, at least in New York ghettos.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Thanks. “Idioms resist manipulation.” Wow.

Comment: Moon puts it better, but I can't access her fine work any longer. I think she sticks with 'variation'.

Comment: “Variations are not disallowed totally” and “there aren’t fixed rules” of making variations, although they can be non-standard. Thankfully I get the idea.